# Excel Function is not working , help please

Tags: excel

Here is my function :

```
=IF( (AND(A3<1/12/6,C12>1020,A1<2/4/60), "Full Protection", IF( AND(A3<1/12/6,C12>1020,A1>2/4/60), "Partial Protection", "No Protection" )))
```

I cannot understand where the error is. Basically what i am trying to do is

> IF the first three conditions are true then the value is=Full
>   protection) elseIF all other three values are true=Partial Protection
>   ELSE then then value=No protection

I m having trouble with the the syntax Excel is using , can anyone help please?

Comment: What is not working? Function returns an error? If yes, which type of error? Function works but gives undesired result? Does Excel say there's a syntax error? Be more specific please.

Comment: The values are Dates, The error is that it keeps outputting the "No protection result".

Comment: You're not properly using the dates. Use the `DATE(y,m,d)` function, e.g. `A3 < DATE(2006, 1, 12)`.

Comment: Which format of dates? `MM/DD/YY`?

Comment: i see that i did not enter the Years correctly and i tried fixing that but i still get the same result, its supposed to be MM/DD/YY . I will try using the date function now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(A3<38729,C12>1020,A1<21950),"Full Protection",IF(AND(A3<38729,C12>1020,A1>21950),"Partial Protection","No Protection"))
```

Note one less parenthesis at the start and end.

Comment: Dont know exactly how it works, im confused about the date values but it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I wish i could give you a +1 one but i cant yet but THANK YOU once again so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using this
=IF(AND(A3<1/12/6,C12>1020,A1<2/4/60),"Full Protection",IF(AND(A3<1/12/6,C12>1020,A1>2/4/60),"Partial Protection","No Protection"))

Comment: it keeps outputting No protection :(

Comment: obvious if the values provided in A1,A3 and C12 cells are not matching with the criteria mentioned then it will results to "No Protection"

Comment: That is the the problem though, the criteria provided should not result in to "no protection" .

Answer (score -1):

if you nead date literals use `DATE` to convert to excel's internal format.
syntax: `DATE(year, month, day)` reference: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/date-function-HP010062283.aspx)

```
=IF( (AND(A3<DATE(2006,12,01),C12>1020,A1<DATE(1960,04,02)), "Full Protection", IF( AND(A3<DATE(2006,12,01),C12>1020,A1>DATE(1960,04,02)), "Partial Protection", "No Protection" )))
```

Comment: I appreciate all of your help friend , however when i try using it, it says that the formula contains en error but nothing more specific than that , i believe there could be a problem with the parentheses with the first AND

Comment: `CDATE()` is not an Excel function, it's VBA.